# Socket.io is not serving socket.io-client library

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, socket.io, client

I started this day with node.js and socket.io. My problem is, that the socket.io server is not serving the client lib of socket.io.

```
var app     = require('express')(),
    express = require('./lib/config/express')(app),
    server  = require('http').createServer(app),
    io      = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    routes  = require('./lib/routes')(app),
    config  = require('./lib/config/config');

app.listen(config.port, function () {
  console.log("foo server started");
});
```

This gives me following output in my console

```
>> File "server.js" changed.

Running "newer:jshint:server" (newer) task
No newer files to process.

Running "express:dev" (express) task
Stopping Express server
Starting background Express server

Running "wait" task
>> Waiting for server reload...
debugger listening on port 5858
**info: socket.io started**
Express server listening on port 9000 in development mode
Done waiting!

Running "watch" task
Completed in 0.516s at Mon Mar 10 2014 22:47:01 GMT+0100 (CET) - Waiting...
```

Anyways, if I want to load the client lib from my angular application

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

it cant be found...

Is there something I misconfigured?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a misconfiguration:

```
var app     = require('express')(),
    express = require('./lib/config/express')(app),
    routes  = require('./lib/routes')(app),
    config  = require('./lib/config/config'),
    server  = app.listen(config.port, function () {}),
    io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

This works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="[your node.js server's location]:[port]/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

`/socket.io/socket.io/js`, to your client, does not exist.

You can also download a the static file from github and place it somewhere with your client files and link to it that way.

Or you can link to a cdn like http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js

Comment: Hey...hm same problem. It cant found the client lib.

Comment: @user3403716 Sorry, I posted some html, but the formatting of this site ignored it. I fixed it now. But I'm glad you fixed your problem anyway!

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Yeah, I'm happy, thats it working now. I'm just beginning with this stuff, but its very cool. :)